# How can I override the 'type' attribute of a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, html, django-widget

Specifically, I would like to render date widget in a form but I would like it to 'be' HTML5 (so I can just forget about the javascript or whatever and trust Chrome, Opera and Safari to display the datepicker).

No javascript solutions please, I have already found those on the web.

Here is a snippet of my code, but it still puts the type attribute of the forms field *thedate* as a "text".

```
#models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thedate = models.DateField()

#forms.py

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'thedate': TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

Can anyone please shed a light?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Using django-html5

1. Install [django-html5](https://github.com/rhec/django-html5/blob/master/html5/forms/widgets.py): `pip install django-html5`
2. In forms.py, `import html5.forms.widgets as html5_widgets`
3. Set `widgets['thedate'] = html5_widgets.DateInput`

I did not personally test it because I just found out the trick but thanks to you I'm probably going to use it :D

### Just override input_type

You can also make your own widget, here's the idea:

```
from django import forms

class Html5DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

Refer to `django/forms/widgets.py` for details ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple one:

put this code in anywhere of the form.py

```
forms.DateInput.input_type="date"
forms.DateTimeInput.input_type="datetime-local"
```

Comment: VERY dirty but efficient. your changing this value for your entire app. monkey patch style though. neither pythonic nor django style.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: should be way easier from the get go. I need it to work, so I use it :)

Answer (score 3):

here's a code snippet of basically jpic's solution and what I used after looking for the answer here too -->

```
class EmailTextInput(django.forms.widgets.TextInput):
    """Subclass TextInput since there's no direct way to override its type attribute"""
    input_type ='email'

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'thedate': EmailTextInput()
        }
```

Comment: It took me forever (in 2022!!!) to find out that DateInput and TimeInput fields in Django are still rendered as `input type="text"`. This is embarrassing. Your solution works.

Comment: bahahaha @kerfuffle :D